# Double integration of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^4}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I am just learning double integration. I am stuck with the following problem:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^4}}\,dx\,dy$$

I am not even sure whether is integral is finite. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: @user3491648 I meant as an improper integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is not finite. For a fixed $y$ (for convenience take $y=0$), we have the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|}dx$

Comment: Does this really mean the integral is not finite? I really doubt that.

Comment: Why would you doubt that?

Comment: Think about it. If the area of a cross section of a figure is infinite, it follows that the volume of the whole figure is infinite.

Comment: It's even stronger than that @recursiverecursion, the area of EVERY cross section of a figure is infinite. This integral is hopelessly divergent

Comment: The last two comments are false. One cross sectional area being infinite does not imply the volume integral is infinite. And plenty of cross sections of this function give finite area: Fix any nonzero $x$ for example; the $y$-integral is finite.

Comment: The $y$ integral certainly is finite,  but as a matter of fact, for every fixed $y$, the $x$ integral is infinite. Just one doesn't matter, I agree, but if every cross sectional area is infinite, then yes the volume integral is infinite.