# Convergence of multiple integral with fixing variable as constant

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

**Problem :**

Let $A$ denotes region inside of $x^2 + y^2=1$.

Determine $$\iint_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA$$

converge or not.

---

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1317648/672369) answer says fix $y=0$ and changes double integral to single integral.

With same process, fix $y=0$.

Then our integral becomes to :

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{|x|}dx$$

and this integral does not converge.

But, with direct calculation, polar coordinate substitution says our original double integral equals to $2\pi$.

---

My question is :

1. Is the answer what I linked above valid?
2. If valid, what mistake did I make?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer that you linked isn't valid for your problem, but it is correct. If you're integrating a function $f(x,y)$, consider the function $G(y) = \int_0^1 f(x,y)dx.$ It is possible for $G(y) = \infty$ on a measure 0 set but also for $\int_0^1 G(y)dy$ to exist and be finite. E.g., we can set $G(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}.$

Comment: I think your understanding of the other problem is incomplete: the goal is to show $\int_{R^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^4}}dx\;dy = \infty.$ The answer you cited says fix any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and note that $G(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^4}}dx = \infty$, not just for $y = 0.$ Now note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(y)dy = \infty$.